# Multiple values for one variable

Tags: shortcode, meta-query, variables

I have a custom plugin that was written by someone, I can't reach anymore. 
It has a search option, that produces a table with seminars in different cities.

Right now I can have a query with this shortcode:

```
[kurssuche class="course_search" place="1"]
```

that shows a table with all seminars in the city "1". How can I produce a table which shows seminars for two or more cities?

I'm new to this, any help is much apprechiated!

This is the code:

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['search']) || $atts['place']!='')
    {
        if(isset($_REQUEST['city']) && $_REQUEST['city'])
        {
            $where[] = "city = '".$_REQUEST['city']."'";
        }
        else if($atts['place'] && $_REQUEST['city']!=='0')
        {
            $where[] = "city = '".$atts['place']."'";
        }

            $courseplanList = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Without looking at the codebase for that plugin there's no way for us to tell if it supports that functionality, let alone how it's implemented.  If I had to take a wild guess I would think it would be `place="1,2,3"` but that's just a guess

Comment: place="1,2" only produces results for the first city. I added the code for the search.

Comment: Please add more of the code. The code produces a MySQL Query, that then is sent to the mysql server (by $wpdb->get_results). Without seeing how the MySQL Query is built exactly, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: The plugin will need modification to look for and accept an array from the `place` attribute.